# What are the known ambiguities in C language grammar?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, c, syntax, syntax-trees

I have found [this reference](https://cs.wmich.edu/%7Egupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm) for the C syntax Backus-Naur Form (BNF). I was wondering if there are any other ambiguities in this grammar other than the infamous "[dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else)"? Also how we can modify the BNF grammar to avoid those ambiguities, including the known one mentioned above?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this answers your question, but I will contribute two details regarding lexing/parsing ambiguities in C in general. I hope these are still helpful.

Consider the expression `T ** c;`. Since C supports type declarations via `typedef`, the parser itself cannot decide whether this is multiplication with variables `T` and `*c` or a variable declaration of a pointer to pointer `c` of type `T**`. We'll need information fed into the parser by the lexer to decide which situation we're parsing (the lexer will resolve each valid type name to a type).

Another situation similar to the situation above gives rise to an ambiguity in the C syntax: In general, statements like `a +++ b` are ambiguous, since both `(a++) + b` and `a + (++b)` are valid. In this kind of situation, the C compiler follows the "longest match" rule: the compiler will match against the *longest* sequence of characters it can match.